# Scapy differentiating between type of ICMP packets

Tags: networking, scapy, icmp

I am using scapy to read ICMP traffic on a given interface. I am expecting ping and traceroute traffic on this interface. How do I differentiate which packet is of type ping and which one of type traceroute?

My current code looks like below

```
import scapy.all as scapy
import socket
from scapy.arch import get_if_hwaddr
from scapy.interfaces import get_if_list
from scapy.layers import http
from scapy.layers.inet import TCP, ICMP, IP
from scapy.layers.inet6 import IPv6
from scapy.layers.l2 import Ether
from uuid import getnode as get_mac

def sniffer(interface):
    #scapy.sniff(iface=interface, filter="icmp6 && ip6[40] == 128", store=False, prn=process_packet)
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface,filter="icmp6", store=False, prn=process_packet)

def process_packet(packet):
    print("DUMP\n")
    print(packet.show(dump=True))
    print(packet[Ether].src)
    print(Ether().src)
    if packet[Ether].src == Ether().src:
        print("OUTGOING PACKET")
        print(packet[IPv6].dst)
    else:
        print("INCOMING PACKET")
    #print(packet.getlayer("ICMPv6 Echo Request").type)


interface = "Wi-Fi"
sniffer(interface)
```

Comment: Traceroutes, in most implementations, *are* just normal pings afaik, so there isn't necessarily a way to differentiate easily. You might need to look at the TTL. If the TTL is large, it's likely a ping, if it's small (< 20), it's likely a traceroute; unless the traceroute is crossing the globe.

Comment: A traceroute to Russia from Canada takes ~17 hops, and pings to the same server have TTLs of 54 at the lowest for me. ~30 might be a good cutoff.

Comment: A more advanced detection would involve tracking TTLs over time. Traceroute's TTLs will increase slowly.

Comment: How do I get packet's TTL in scapy? In the packet dump I am getting, there is no ttl.

Comment: The `IP` layer has a `ttl` field

Comment: It has IPv6 layer that does not have any ttl field